# Loading image from URL in background: Android compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to load image from network using Coil accompanist library.
I am getting frame drops due to the same.

```
I/Choreographer: Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Is there a way to load images in background thread?
Here is my code :

```
 val painter = rememberCoilPainter(request = url)

    Card(modifier = modifier) {
      when (painter.loadState) {
        is ImageLoadState.Success ->
          Image(
            painter = painter,
            contentDescription = title,
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
          )
        else ->
          Image(
            painter = rememberCoilPainter(request = R.drawable.placeholder),
            contentDescription = title,
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
          )
      }
    }
```

This code is the content part of *LazyRow* and there are around 20-25 items in the list.

Please suggest a way to perform the image loading in background thread to avoid frame drops.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is enough to improve your performance.

You can start improving the use of the placeholder drawables which can set be on the request.
Something like:

```
    Image(
        painter = rememberCoilPainter(
            request = "url",
            requestBuilder = {
                placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
            }
        ),
        contentDescription = null)
```

Comment: I tried using ImageRequest but still there are frame drops :( Here is my code :


    val imageRequest = ImageRequest.Builder(context)
        .data(url)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
        .error(R.drawable.error)
        .build()

     Image(
          painter = rememberCoilPainter(request = imageRequest),
          contentDescription = title,
          contentScale = ContentScale.FillBounds
        )